# How to link project folder to svn repository?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have checked out project from svn repository, and moved it to different machine. Now how do i link this folder to svn repository, so that svn operations(update, commit etc.) are enabled on this folder.

Comment: As long as the URL to the repository hasn't changed you shouldn't need to do anything, as the .svn folder with the metadata is already in the repository.

Comment: Apologies, I meant working copy instead of repository above. As long as Subversion is installed on the new machine you should be able to run all the regular commands from within your working copy without issue.

Comment: sorry, but i am not able to do any svn operations. svn not able to recognize working folder.

Comment: Is the .svn folder present in the root folder of the working copy you moved to the new machine?

Answer (score 4):

I think this is an issue caused due to the difference in SVN versions across the machines.I recently moved over my projects to a newer 64-Bit machine, installed SVN and the projects were not linked to the repository.

If you have the .svn folder then 
 Right click in open window and you should see an option "SVN Upgrade working copy". 
 Click that option and a pop up with Upgrade as an option will appear.
 Click Ok and that should link the project to the repository.

**EDIT: Since Stack Overflow discourages posting links I am uploading the screenshots below.**

Folder structure with SVN folder

[image: SVN1]

Right click in open window and you should see an option "SVN Upgrade working copy".

[image: SVN2]

Click that option and a pop up with Upgrade as an option will appear.

[image: SVN3]

Click Ok and that should link the project to the repository.

[image: SVN4]

Comment: Sir, you are my savior!

Answer (score 0):

You're using Tortiose SVN, so right click the working copy and under tortoise SVN menu you should see a relocate option (just after export)
This lets you set the path to the repository.
If you've moved a working copy to a machine with a drive mapped differently or that requires a different path to the repository this is where you set it.

Also (lets try the obvious!) does the new machine have Tortoise SVN installed?

Answer (score 0):

Ever since the .svn folder was moved to the top level only, I've run into this issue a couple times. If you have a subfolder you've copied elsewhere, you can reconnect it to the repository by doing a checkout on it.

It won't overwrite any changes that might exist.